# ruby on rails $ mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am configure the mysql instead of sqlite3 and the output is :

```
=> Booting WEBrick    
=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000   
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 24, col 18: `' (ArgumentError)   
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'  
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:927:in `database_configuration'  
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:437:in `initialize_database'   
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'   
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'  
        from C:/rails/rail/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'    
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'  
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'  
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'  
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'  
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'  
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'  
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'  
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'  
        from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong here? It seems like there is something wrong with the
 code because it doesn't work. I will appreciate a lot the help
from yours

here is my yml file for mysql

```
development:      
adapter: mysql   
database: test  
username:false  
password:neha  
host :localhost  
port:3306
```

Comment: show your configuration that doesn't work

Comment: There is a button in the editor to ident your code

Comment: username: false ! is this your database name?

Comment: no my database name is test and username is false

Comment: ahh, I missed it, I was asking is your username is false?

Comment: then you should change it to something else, because it will be parsed  as boolean type. also format your yml as per Hitesh's suggestion and instead of tab use double space _ _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use above tab sequence in all of your environment

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 database: test
 username:false
 password:neha
 host :localhost
 port:3306
```

Comment: in all enviornment means,please b exlpicit

Comment: same format for all environment keys like development,production,test etc

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

1. `host :localhost` should be `host: localhost`. Note the position of the `:` character - having it after the space is what gives you that syntax error. I get exactly the same stacktrace if the YAML is set up as you have it.
2. You need to indent the attributes of the `development` hash. This won't make the YAML invalid, but it will give you the wrong result. If you don't indent, you'll get a series of key => value hashes, instead of a hash containing a `development` key, which in turn has child attributes for the configuration params.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your YAML configuration. **Syck** is YAML parser that fails to load YAML configuration files. Check the configuration for typos, especially *config/database.yml*.

Also, use `username:"false"` in your configuration. *true* of *false* without quotes will be interpreted as *TrueClass*, not *String*, and that might cause trouble.